# Where are appRTC default parameters specified?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

AppRTC, the webRTC demo app, includes a long list of parameters.  These can be set in the URL, as explained:  https://apprtc.appspot.com/params.html

Where/how are the default parameters set programatically within the code?

For example, if we want to change the default timeout (tt) or the default send bitrate (vrbr), where in the appRTC code is this done?  It turns out that finding where the parameters are set in the code is not as trivial as it sounds.  There doesn't seem to be a central location for parameter defaults, and the logic of where to change default values is not clear even with some code analysis.  The parameters are set and reset many times and can be set in many ways, and they are passed via HTTP through different codebases on multiple machines.

Thanks